# Issue with downloading files via Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to download file via Retrfoit and everything goes well, until I'm opening it, because after that the only things that I see either a black screen (for images) or some kid of error about wrong file format. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

File creation sources:

```
val file = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), event.fileName)
```

ResponseBody converting sources:

```
private fun writeResponseBodyToDisk(body: ResponseBody, file: File): Boolean {
    return try {
        // todo change the file location/name according to your needs
        val futureStudioIconFile: File = file
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
            val fileSize: Long = body.contentLength()
            var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0
            inputStream = body.byteStream()
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile)
            while (true) {
                val read: Int = inputStream.read(fileReader)
                if (read == -1) {
                    break
                }
                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()
                Timber.d("%s%s", "file download: $fileSizeDownloaded of ", fileSize)
            }
            outputStream.flush()

            viewState.value = ViewState.ShowFile(file)
            true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            false
        } finally {
            inputStream?.close()
            outputStream?.close()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        false
    }
}
```

Viewwing sources:

```
val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider",
                state.file
            )
            startActivity(
                Intent.createChooser(
                    Intent().apply {
                        action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
                        clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", fileUri)
                        type = "*/*"
                        addFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                        )
                    },
                    null
                )
            )
```

Logs:

```
file download: 4096 of 21688
file download: 8192 of 21688 
file download: 12288 of 21688
file download: 16384 of 21688
file download: 20480 of 21688
file download: 21688 of 21688
```

Comment: From where you are getting that `event.fileName`

Comment: @MoCoding it's not relevant part, I receive file name from server, then create file with that name, and write info inside

Comment: So the extension in that file name is correct ?

Comment: It is relevant. You should tell what the value is or otherwise hardcode a name. We dont know what you are doing.

Comment: @MoCoding yes it is

Comment: `Timber.d("%s%s", "file download: $fileSizeDownloaded of ", fileSize)
            }` You could have told us which file size was logged.

Comment: @MoCoding hey, I noticed that inputStrem.read(fileReader) causing IOException with message "closed". I think this is the problem, but I don't understand why is that

Comment: give us more informations about your code, and add that Exception for your questions so we can understand the problem.

Comment: @MoCoding I attached logs for size